# Convert Datetime formats and merge two OHLC timeseries on pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, time-series

**My Plan:**

I have two different datasets with OHLC values, one representing the Weekly (1W) timeframes: `weekly_df` and the other representing the hourly (1H) timeframes `hourly_df`.

Here's what the two data frame looks like:

[image: Here's how the two data frame looks like.]

My goal is to merge the weekly OHLC values to the hourly df by using [pandas merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) and followed by `ffill`. However, Before I do it, I need to get the `date` columns in the same format and type. Meaning I need to reformat the weekly dates with `00:00:00` after the date. Here's how I'm doing it:

[image]

**The Problem:**

Once this is done, everything is now a string and when I try to convert it back to datetime, the `00:00:00` in the date column disappears:

[image]

Once this is done, I wanted to merge the data frames by the `date` and `fill`, so that all the hourly OHLC values in a given date also have a column displaying their weekly OHLC value.
As of right now, this is **not working** as the merge only merges the dates common between he data frames and omits the rest:

[image]

If there is an easier way to do it? As most of the methods I have tried are returning an error.

**The two data frame CSV files:**

Incase you need to test it, here are the two CSV files:
[Hourly](https://drive.google.com/file/d/114-PSd556zwRFkMhLKQGANo3jqHUV_lu/view?usp=sharing)
[Weekly](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1or66kzYYOIwBkykXph3Eyfn0UNgcN_mh/view?usp=sharing)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi there. Pandas has a merge operation to merge on non-exact datetimes. It's not 100% what you asked for, but it might solve your problem. Google `pd.merge_asof()` or read https://angwalt12.medium.com/the-hidden-rules-of-pandas-merge-asof-e67293a5318e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For anyone who would face a similar issue in the future, here's how I fixed it:**

Since the datetime format applied on the dataframe is not enforcing `00:00:00`, I have done an offset to the time by 1 second as `00:00:01` to both the dataframes as follows:

```
hourly_df['date'] = hourly_df['date'] + pd.DateOffset(seconds=1)
```

This helps me enforce the same format on the weekly df by offsetting it with 1 sec.

Finally as I now have the same `date` columns I can `merge` & `ffill` them as follows:

```
merged_df = hourly_df.merge(weekly_df ,on =['date'], how='left').ffill()
```

which merges and displays the result as follows:

[image]

Do let me know if anyone else finds another way to solve this by keeping the original time. Cheers!